# Django-paginator + Javascript | Cómo contar respuestas correctas y no perder el dato

Tags: javascript, django

Un usuario responde una pregunta tras otra, y si es correcta se cuenta y se guarda el valor contado en la etiqueta `<h5>`. Claro que como cada pregunta está en una página de *Paginator* (Django), la página se refresca y se pierde el valor guardado en la etiqueta `<h5>` (comienza con el 0, y se va cambiando el valor, o esa es la idea).

¿Cómo puedo contar sin perder el dato y sin utilizar la base de datos? ¿Hay otra mejor manera?

```js
if (respuesta == "correcta") {
  var correctas = 0;
  valcorrectas = document.getElementById('respCorrectas').innerHTML;
  valcorrectas = parseInt(valcorrectas) + 1;
  document.getElementById('respCorrectas').innerHTML = valcorrectas;
}
```

```html
<h5 id="respCorrectas" style="display:none">0</h5>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pdrías usar el [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) para almacenar el valor y persistirlo en el navegador. Siempre que el navegador no sea cerrado o la pestaña de la página sea cerrada, podrás establecer y obtener el valor almacenado en dicho objeto.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var correctas = window.sessionStorage.getItem('correctas');

if(correctas) { // si el elemento existe debo convertirlo a tipo Integer
  correctas = parseInt(correctas);
} else {
  correctas = 0;
}

// ahora viene la lógica para aumentar el contador si la respuesta es correcta
// supongo que eso lo haces en algún botón de acción
if(respuesta == "correcta"){
  // aumentamos el contador
  correctas++;
  //almacenamos el valor en el sessionStorage
  window.sessionStorage.setItem('correctas', correctas);
}
```

De esta forma al cargar la nueva pregunta, se ejecuta el código que verifica si existe la variable `correctas` en el Objeto `sessionStorage`, la convierte en entero.

Cuando la página carga por primera vez, la variable no existe en el `sessionStorage`, es por ello que la establece a 0, para iniciar el contador.

Espero que de esta forma puedas solventar el problema.